# Total Count by Group

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get a count by group, "group" meaning a consecutive collection of rows where Charge (column B), is either 0 or non-zero. In the example below, the column named Results is what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: How difficult would it be to have the results in different rows. For example, the count by group of Zero charge in column d & the count by group of non-zero in column e?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2=0,B3<>0),AND(B2<>0,B3=0)),ROW(1:1)-SUM($D$1:$D1),"")
```

This tests if the charge is changing to or from 0, then it takes the row number and subtracts the already posted amounts.

Thus it will only post the difference.

Comment: Nice solution!  And I note that `OR(AND(B2=0,B3<>0),AND(B2<>0,B3=0))` can be further simplified into `XOR(B2=0,B3=0)`.  i.e. the whole formula could be simplified as `=IF(XOR(B2=0,B3=0),ROW(1:1)-SUM($D$1:$D1),"")`